# iOS list of available bluetooth-devices with information programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, bluetooth

I am new in this community. I need help solving a problem with Bluetooth in Objective-C.
I want to discover all available bluetooth-devices and get information about an existing connection. (Not a scan for peripherals!) Is this possible in iOS? For example the list in Settings > Bluetooth!

Comment: No, it isn't possible

Comment: you need which type of information ??

Comment: as Apple is very conscious about privacy and security, they dont provide any API to get any information beyond the connections required for the app to run smoothly, to maintain integrity and security of other connections running due to other app or process

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. It depends on your setup.

No, this is not possible using a public API.

Yes, it is technically possible with the `BluetoothManager.framework`. My demo project [BeeTee](https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee)¹ shows how and encapsulate the underlying part.

However, based on the [AppStore guideline §2.5](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) on private (undocumented) functions it is not possible to publish apps with the *BeeTee* and `BluetoothManager.framework` in the AppStore.

If you decide to go with the BeeTee framework, you could easily list all Bluetooth devices in range:

```
class Demo: BeeTeeDelegate {
    let beeTee = BeeTee()

    init() {
        beeTee.delegate = self
        beeTee.enableBluetooth()
        beeTee.startScanForDevices()
    }

    func receivedBeeTeeNotification(notification: BeeTeeNotification) {
        switch notification {
        case .DeviceDiscovered:
            for device in beeTee.availableDevices {
                print(device)
            }
        default:
            print(notification)
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using iOS 11, please consider also the [pull request #16](https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee/pull/16). Unfortunately, I am too busy at the moment to merge this pull request yet.

¹ I am the author of [BeeTee](https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee). :-)